# Does h2o supports multidimensional output?

Tags: r, h2o

Does h2o supports multidimensional output ? I would like to train NN on data where input is 81-dimensional and output variable is also 81-dimensional vector.

Comment: Fair warning that I have never used h2o - but what if you specify same variables in `y` as for `x`?

Comment: you can't rf example of syntax : `drf <- h2o.randomForest(x=feature.names, y='outcome', training_frame,train.hex, ntrees =500)`

Comment: @Roman Luštrik do you now any other tool which allows for multidimensional output  ?

Comment: tensorflow and mxnet supports multidimensional output. Both libraries have R API.

Answer (score 1):

No, H2O does not currently support learning on multidimensional outcomes.